# Secure Excel Workbook (with VBA) from reuse with different data

Tags: vba, excel, security

I have created an Excel Workbook with a lot of VBA code for a customer.  The customer will provide me with data. I will import that data into the VBA laden template, Save it as an xlsm, and deliver it to the customer. I get paid by the Workbook so I need to prevent them from trying to copy new data into the existing workbook and reusing it.

**How can I *somehow* prevent the customer from reusing a workbook by just entering in new data on the main Worksheet, then saving as a new Workbook**, and getting the use of the VBA code for free. (Alternately they could copy the file in windows then enter new data on the copied version.) **I need to detect a *significant* change in data from the initial imported data.**

The data on the main sheet is fairly static (perhaps even totally static on many known columns). I'm thinking about randomly sampling some of the cell data on import (perhaps 10 random cells, or number of rows, etc.), and storing that data *somewhere*. If, say, 50% of the cells change data, I could just disable (or short-circuit) the public entry points in the code...or something else?

I'd like to allow for *some* flexibility on the part of the customer, but prevent abuse.

- Is there a better way than my general idea, above?
- Where could I store that data (it should be part of the sheet, but not changeable by the customer). Perhaps a hidden sheet with password locked cells?
- Is there some accepted way of doing this that I'm unaware of?

Comment: How much is your time worth? How many sheets of data would the customer need to attempt to defraud you with to make it worth your time to test this? This sounds like more of an issue with the contract terms than any code.

Comment: I will not be in a position to check use or misuse. Not only would I probably never know, I wouldn't be in a good position *at all* to verify if I suspected something.  I think many (many!) of these files will be ordered. I also suspect some subcontractors *will* attempt abuse. If they figure out a method, I could be totally replaced, and only see my numbers slowly dwindle. Let me put it this way: It is WELL worth my time.

Comment: If your customers are not technically knowledgeable you could encode the sheet data into a "hash" and add that to your VBA code (then password protect the project).  All of that you could do using VBA.  Of course, it's possible to crack the VBA project password if you know how to use Google...  EDIT: re-reading your question you seem to want to allow for *some* editing, so a hash may not work out, but some other less-visible way of storing the original data (Custom XML part?) might work.

Comment: Just to echo @TimWilliams - if a user is determined to get to your code that's stored in an Excel file, there are myriad ways they can try to get in.  Excel's (Office's?) security isn't that hard to break if you really want to.  How tech. savvy are your clients? Why not just run your macros on the data, then save just the data and give that to the customer? Do they *need* to have the `.xlsm` or would simply `.xlsx` work?

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes there is a reason: it's all their data. I'm just adding automated ways to enter metadata, track, and report that data. It's the VB they are purchasing.

Comment: They're purchasing the VB, but you want to lock them out of seeing it?  I think this question is less of an SO issue, and more of a contractual one, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: They are purchasing a workbook that has vb functionality. I *will* contract appropriately. I'm asking how to protect in *case* of infringement. As stated above I will not be able to verify if they are *upholding* the contract. I think this is an appropriate question: **I'm asking about a functional way to detect spreadsheet data change after initial import (in a secure way, or as secure as possible).** The "contractual" stuff is a red herring.

Comment: Ah I see.  I think this is more suited perhaps for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/). For the record, I don't know if I'd trust my business/IP to the security of MS Office.

Comment: Ok, well, since I want *some* flexibility in the changing of data, it does seem like the solution will be code based. I'm hoping for some good input.

Comment: what sort of flexibility you have to give to the customer? Is this flexibility achieved by code? Does the customer need to change data in the main sheet?

Comment: How periodically they provide the data to be processed?

Comment: There are some columns that they can completely change. I know what these are...I don't track them (in my proposed solution). There are some columns that should be considered static data...but I'd like to allow for some administrative type corrections (perhaps a spelling error, or fix a typo, or even add, remove an entire row). 

This flexibility would be done by them simply modifying the core data in the main sheet directly (outside of the already identified columns that are expected to change.)

Comment: re: how periodic:  
I'll use a template. They give me a sheet with raw data, I import that into my vb laden template, Save As a new sheet (xlsm), and send them that new sheet. So after I import into the template and save as, there should never be a reimport or drastic change to the static data on the saved sheet (but still allow for *some* administrative adjustments of the "static" columns).

Comment: so do you just receive the data and return to the it processed once, or you received at a later date and batch of data to be processed and returned, if so how periodically this happens?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question...it might need to be reworded a bit, but I think the answer is this: I receive data, *I* import it into the vba excel sheet. I save it and give them this new vba inclusive copy. Data is not imported into that saved version again (thus the whole point of this question). I will receive, import, save, and deliver new sheets potential several times a week.

Comment: Out of curiosity, could this not be done via a web portal? so the customer can upload their file and you can provide them the interface to make amendments as per their requirement. You can than run your code (server side) and give the results in expected format (i.e. Excel worksheet or XML). Admittedly this will probably require major rework on your side but it does give you more control

Comment: My understanding is that your VBA code does two _things_: 1) process new data; and this is what your customer is currently paying you for 2) give your customer some browsing and querying utilities over processed data. If that is the case you could separate functions in two different xlsm and give your customer the 2nd one only. Sorry if my understanding is wrong

Comment: The best I can do here is tell you that it is *like* the following: 1. The customer has an existing workbook that has a page of thousands of widgets. 2. Each widget is listed on a row with information about the widget. 3. I import the widget data to a new workbook and sheet. 4. *The new sheet allows them to enter many-to-one cross-reference items for each widget* with custom vba entry form(s) and vba data-validation(s) and vba summary information (for the widget row). I make it easy and fast for them to enter validated cross-reference data.

Comment: So the main functionalities are data querying summarizing, and cross validation, and these functionalities depend on current data versioning (otherwise I wouldn't understand your customer recurrent need of your services) you could split your data processing in such a way to get to the point of writing down all needed "versioning dependant" subcalculated tables and then 1) turn custom vba entry (user?)forms into sheet forms with ActiveX controls referencing those "static" ranges 2) have data validation reference those "static" ranges again 3) leave little vba for "final" summarizations

Comment: This way you would pass them a workbook with "metadata" they would need your "1st step" vba to distill from new data. The workbook would be heavier but "semi-static"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Perhaps Time-expire the functionality in your code**

So thank you for this question.  Thank you for setting a bounty.  It is a very interesting question given your desire to monetise the VBA code, as a VBA programmer I generally resign myself to not being able to monetise VBA code.  It is good that you insist and I will contribute an attempt at an answer.

Firstly, let me join the chorus of answers that say VBA is easily hacked.  The password protection can be broken.  I would join the chorus of respondents who say you should pick a compiled language as the vessel for your code.  Why not try C# or VB.NET housed in a Visual Studio Tools For Office (VSTO) .NET assembly?

VSTO will associate a compiled assembly with a workbook.  This mechanism is worth knowing because if you insist on VBA we can use the same mechanism (see later).  Each workbook has a CustomDocumentProperties collection where one can set custom properties (it says Document not Spreadsheet because the same can be found in Word so Document is the generalised case).

Excel will look at the workbook's CustomDocumentProperties collection and search for "_AssemblyName" and "_AssemblyLocation"; if _AssemblyName is an asterisk then it knows it needs to load a .NET/VSTO assembly, the _AssemblyLocation provides a lookup to the file to load (you'll have to dig in on this, I forget the details).    [Reference](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9qtENHmR6OwC&pg=SA2-PA97&lpg=SA2-PA97&dq=vsto%20documentproperties&source=bl&ots=puYQTftNYB&sig=HYeOV1v6U45uq7_7ZHpdGQ_oh5I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAlMGd-9rPAhXpJ8AKHcPfDuw4ChDoAQghMAI#v=onepage&q=vsto%20documentproperties&f=false)

Anyway, I'm reminded of VSTO CustomDocumentProperties mechanism because if you insist on using VBA then I suggest storing a value in the CustomDocumentProperties collection that helps you time expire the functionality of your code.  Note do not use the BuiltInDocumentProperties("Creation Date") because it is easily identifiable; instead use a codeword, say "BlackHawk".  Here is some sample code.

```
Sub WriteProperty()

    ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Creation Date") = CDate("13/10/2016 19:15:22")


    If IsEmpty(CustomDocumentPropertiesItemOERN(ThisWorkbook, "BlackHawk")) Then
        Call ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Add("BlackHawk", False, MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeDate, Now())
    End If


End Sub

Function CustomDocumentPropertiesItemOERN(ByVal wb As Excel.Workbook, ByVal vKey As Variant)
    On Error Resume Next
    CustomDocumentPropertiesItemOERN = wb.CustomDocumentProperties.Item(vKey)
End Function


Sub ReadProperty()

    Debug.Print "ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties(""Creation Date""):=" & ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Creation Date")
    Debug.Print "CustomDocumentPropertiesItemOERN(ThisWorkbook, ""BlackHawk""):=" & CustomDocumentPropertiesItemOERN(ThisWorkbook, "BlackHawk")

End Sub
```

So you could set CustomDocumentProperty "BlackHawk" to the workbook's initial creation time and then allow the client to use the code for 24 hours, or even 48 hours (careful with weekends, create Friday work through to Tuesday) and then afterwards the code can refuse to operate and instead throw a message saying pay LimaNightHawk more money!

P.S.  Good luck with your revenue model.

P.P.S. I read your profile, thanks for your military service.

Comment: 1st I'm not going to time expire my workbook. Still I chose this as the answer because of the TYPE of approach. I think to solve the issue, it will require the use of the two elements in this solution: 1. the dependency on a compiled file (assembly, dll, etc.).  2. a way to communicate the uniqueness of the workbook. --- I'll have to think of the best way to incorporate the two, but whatever I do, the next person with the issue will have to figure out their own individualized implementation of these two elements. 

Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do it will be feasible to crack it (VBA code is easy to crack). However:

- there is the contract so... that's not legal for them to do it
- you can put part of the code on a FTP server and control physically what is being executed

Very nices ideas here though

Answer (score 1):

Compile Excel file to EXE. Google for that.

Comment: I find this a very interesting option. Due consideration.

Comment: If you decide to buy any software of third party, be prepared that what you need, is the top most expensive license offered. Do not think that anything like "home" of "small business" license will suffice. Ask for the price for developers, so that any trace of third party will not be in your worksheet. Read carefully agreements, EULA etc.

Answer (score 0):

Concern 1 seems to be basic re-use of the file.  You could create a sub in the ThisWorkbook module to destroy code located in other modules in the event that save-as is selected.

Concern 2 seems to be someone hacking your password protection. A similar tactic could be employed such as using "opening the developer window" as your event instead of save as.

I have experimented with save events to log user entries with great success using the ThisWorkbook module. I am not certain how/if one could detect if the developer tab is opened.

Comment: Ok. Good thoughts. I'm not sure about the "Save As" though. They could just copy the file and rename it in Windows. And if they did, I'm not sure I care. I DO care if they then paste a whole bunch of new data on the sheet and try to reuse it.

Comment: Events can be disable by users and enable back as they wish `Application.EnableEvents = False`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've done. Perhaps there is a entirely better approach, or there are tweeks to the below that will make it better:

1. From the VBA Tools menu > VBAProject Properties > Protection (tab), I Locked the project for viewing with a password.
2. I created a new "License" sheet. 
   This sheet is hidden from the user. If you hide the sheet via code like this:

`Me.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden`

then then sheet cannot be un-hidden by the user (it requires running vba code to unhide).

3. On initial import I sample:

   - Number of imported rows
   - x number of randomly selected cells *from the columns I know won't/shouldn't change. (There are columns they are allowed to change freely.)

I store these on the "License" sheet in **Address** / **Value** pairs.

[image]

4. When the workbook is opened, the `Workbook_Open` event fires and then does a quick comparison of the *current* number of rows, and the *current* values for the addresses stored on the "License" sheet.  I then do a percentage calculation: If the rows are more than x% different, or the number of changed values is more that y% then I

```vb
Sheets(1).Protect LOCKOUT_PASSWORD
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

There is also a method for unlocking the sheets if necessary.

Comment: Also need to protect the workbook structure otherwise, with your workbook active, this code makes the `License` sheet visible `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("License").Visible = xlSheetVisible`

Comment: Suggest to use a Change Event rather that Workbook_Open as users can disable events just before opening the workbook and set it back afterwards.  `Application.EnableEvents = False`

Comment: Ok, but in both comments above, doesn't step 1 prevent that?  I've locked the vba code. Am I missing something.

Comment: It can be done from other workbook, or even from the immediate window...

Comment: what about my other questions, I'm trying to help you but can't if you don't provide information...

Comment: WOW! Another workbook! That's a backdoor I really hadn't thought of. (Darn!)
As for your other question, I'm not sure I understand. If I use the Change event, can't they still disable events, make the change, then re-enable? I'm sure you have a good point here...I'm just not getting it.

Comment: If you put a password, they can crack it ==> they know how you check the license. 
Then they open with disabled event, modify the license and done.
==> see my above answer: there is no way that will be but "time consuming", except putting some of the actual code, what does the job, on a server or a DLL...

Answer (score 0):

This might be too simple of an answer, but sometimes we fail to think of the simplest solutions:

Why don't you simply provide the customer with only a copy of the output? You could run their data through your macro-enabled workbook, copy the output sheet into a new workbook, and then break all links so that there's no formulas, updating, or ties to your workbook.

Comment: If only.  In this case it won't work. What they need is the vba-automated data entry and data-processing stuff I'm giving them, including stuff like user forms.

Keep thinking out of the box. It looks like that what it's going to take.

Answer (score -1):

I would create another workbook that contains the code and then reference the customers wb from that one.